# How can I avoid manually specifying my private key file when using PuTTY's pscp command?

Tags: putty, ssh-keys, pscp

I have installed PuTTY and configured public/private key pairs that work nicely from inside PuTTY.

When I use `pscp`, I find that I have to use the `-i *keyfile*` option to specify the private key (I have the keys in the `C:\users\username\.ssh` directory)

I notice that the online examples of `pscp` that I see don't use the `-i` option.

Is there a specific directory I need to place the key files in, or is there something similar in concept to the "config" file used in the private key directory on Linux?

I was expecting not to have to manually specify the private key file when using `pscp`.

Answer (score 1):

PuTTY tools do not look for keys in any fixed location.

All you can do is to save the path to your private key to *"Default Settings"* in PuTTY GUI. I wouldn't recommend that.

Better is to load your keys to Pageant. The `pscp` picks them up automatically from there.